# How can I create multiple Spring beans in a @Bean-annotated method or anything similar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In a Spring application that uses HTTP remoting, I have a service façade module configured as follows (I made the code generic to improve clarity):

```
@Configuration
public class MyFacadeConfig {

  private HttpInvokerServiceExporter facade(Class<?> cls) {
    HttpInvokerServiceExporter bean = new HttpInvokerServiceExporter();
    // The service referred to by this exporter is already instantiated as another Spring bean with all its dependencies.
    bean.setService(appContext.getBean(cls));
    bean.setServiceInterface(cls);
    return bean;
  }

  @Bean("/first.service")
  public HttpInvokerServiceExporter firstServiceFacade() {
    return facade(FirstService.class);
  }

  @Bean("/second.service")
  public HttpInvokerServiceExporter secondServiceFacade() {
    return facade(SecondService.class);
  }

  // ... and so on for the 37 other services

}
```

where `FirstService` and `SecondService` are interfaces with existing implementations whose detail is not needed here.

I have another module that defines 39 proxies (instances of `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean`) corresponding to each of my services exposed through my façade.

So far, everything works properly.

But I would like to make the code more generic, elegant, and robust while mitigating the risk of error (e.g., a bad mapping between a service and its proxy in the future). The way I would like to do this is as follows:

First, I move the façade/proxy metadata into an enumeration:

```
public enum ConfigBeansFacade {

  FIRST("/first", FirstService.class),
  SECOND("/second", SecondService.class)
  // ... and so on for the 37 other services
  ;

  private String beanName;
  private Class<?> serviceInterface;

  // Constructor and getters

  public String getCompleteBeanName() {
    return beanName + ".service";
  }

}
```

Then the configuration of the façade would be simplified in a style similar to the following:

```
@Configuration
public class MyFacadeConfig {

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;

  @Autowired
  public void configExporters() {
    for (ConfigBeansFacade bean : ConfigBeansFacade.values()) {
      HttpInvokerServiceExporter exp = new HttpInvokerServiceExporter();
      exp.setService(beanFactory.getBean(bean.getServiceInterface()));
      exp.setServiceInterface(bean.getServiceInterface());
      beanFactory.registerSingleton(bean.getCompleteBeanName(), exp);
    }
  }

}
```

I tried every single recipe I found in online forums, including StackOverflow, but there are two constraints not met elsewhere:

1. When defining the exporters, the underlying services are other Spring beans that are instantiated, initialized, and registered with their own configuration and dependencies through the standard Spring mechanics. There is no direct class instantiation other than the exporters themselves.
2. I thought about grouping the exporters into a single collection as suggested by some people. The only problem is that Spring MVC uses the `HttpInvokerServiceExporter` Spring bean names as endpoint URIs when registering the exporters into its own configuration. I must therefore register each exporter as a “first-class citizen” bean with its own bean name into the application context.

Given these constraints, the problem I have arises in (1) when I try to retrieve the underlying services to be encapsulated into exporters: they are not necessarily ready yet, which results into `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`s.

I tried solutions with a `@PostContruct`-annotated method, with a `BeanPostProcessor`, with an `@Autowired` method (as shown above), nothing is working as required.

Does anyone know about a way or a technique to initialize and register multiple beans inside a single method under my constraints described above? Such a method doesn't need to be annotated with `@Bean`, `@Autowired`, or any other specific annotation, it's just an example of what I tried.

In the client module, mercifully, the `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` instances need only the interfaces and the bean names, so constraint (1) above should not apply.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I've understood what you're trying to do but I wonder if you could try autowiring a `List` of beans that implement an interface?

e.g.

```
public interface MyService {
  String getKey();
  void doStuff();
}
```

Then implement as many of these as you require

e.g.

```
@Component
public class FirstService implements MyService {
  public String getKey() {
    return "/first";
  }
  public void doStuff() {
    ...
  }
}
```

then have a factory bean with the autowired list

```
@Component
public class MyServiceFactory {

  private final List<MyService> services;

  @Autowired
  public MyServiceFactory(List<MyService> services) {
      this.services = services;
  }
}
```

To add more implementations of MyService, simply add them as @Component and Spring magically picks them up and adds them to the list.

Sometimes I find it useful to access my implementations via a Map

```
@Component
public class MyServiceFactory {

  private final Map<String, MyService> services;

  @Autowired
  public MyServiceFactory(List<MyService> services) {
      this.services = services
        .stream()
        .collect(toMap(MyService::getKey, Function.identity()));
  }

  public MyService getServiceByKey(String key) {
    return services.get(key);
  }
}
```

I find this keeps each implementation nice and self contained (and easy to test). Spring automatically picks up all the components that implement my interface without the factory having a huge number of imports. And I can test the factory easily by mocking the list of implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Using a list or a map was part of my reflections. The issue is the Spring MVC internal mechanics using `HttpInvokerServiceExporter` bean names as endpoint URIs. If I use such a list or map, the exporter beans will not be configured as endpoints by the Spring MVC infrastructure.